# Windows 8 Set User Account Image

Tags: windows-8, console-application, user-accounts

I'm trying to write a small CONSOLE (not metro style) app to quickly change the user account image of the current user to a select image for a setup scrip that I'm running on a bunch of laptops.

They're all Windows 8 and (since it hasn't been out terribly long) I can't find a ton of info on it. I did manage to figure out that you need to use the [Windows.System.UserProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241881.aspx) object to do so, but I can't find any documentation on how to do so in a console app.

Thoughts? Suggestions?

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToCallWinRTAPIsInWindows8FromCDesktopApplicationsWinRTDiagram.aspx

Comment: Certainly helped, but now I can't get past these damn permissions issues. You need to set the running app as a useraccountpicture client or something in order for it to be allowed to modify the user account picture, but when I added the exception to do that in the programs manifest nothing happened, and it was still disallowed.