# Setting Windows 8 account picture with .NET/WinRT hybrid

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

Basically I'm trying to set a Windows 8 account picture from a "Console Application". The only API to set the picture that I found is in the WinRT API. Basically the same question ([Windows 8 Set User Account Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883096/windows-8-set-user-account-image)) led me at least being able to build the hybrid, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
private static async Task SetAccountPicture(string employeeId)
{
    // Download image
    string imagePath = DownloadImage(employeeId);

    // Set account picture
    Stream fileStream = File.Open(imagePath, FileMode.Open);
    IRandomAccessStream winRTStream = await DotNetToWinRTStream(fileStream);
    SetAccountPictureResult result = await UserInformation.SetAccountPicturesFromStreamsAsync(null, winRTStream, null);

    // Clean up download file
    File.Delete(imagePath);
}

public static async Task<IRandomAccessStream> DotNetToWinRTStream(Stream dotNetStream)
{
    IBuffer buffer;
    var inputStream = dotNetStream.AsInputStream();
    using (var reader = new DataReader(inputStream))
    {
        await reader.LoadAsync((uint)dotNetStream.Length);
        buffer = reader.DetachBuffer();
    }

    var memoryStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    await memoryStream.WriteAsync(buffer);
    return memoryStream;
}
```

The SetAccountPictureResult says 'failure' without any other information. What could be happening here?